# Lua and caching data

Tags: caching, lua, redis, memcached

I am really new to Lua and I have been working on side projects but cannot seem to figure out ways to cache data in Lua.

What I am trying to do is:

I want to cache data that I fetch from my database so I can get those variables instantly without going through calculation(fetching) again.

I found resources on resty-memcached and redis-lua scripting but they seem not related to what I want to do.

It would be very nice if someone could help me! Thaks!

Comment: You can simply implement LRU-cache in Lua.